# Importing an ES6 module using jspm & using in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia, jspm, es6-module-loader

I'm trying to use the [querystring](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) package in an Aurelia application but getting `Cannot read property 'stringify' of undefined` error in the browser console.

These are the steps I took:

- Install using `jspm install querystring`
- Add `import {querystring} from 'querystring'` into the Aurelia model
- Use in my model like so:

  ```
  import {querystring} from 'querystring';

  export class App {

  criteria_words;
  criteria_location;

  constructor() {
  }

  submit() {
      console.log(querystring.stringify(this));
  }
  }
  ```

What step am I missing?

Comment: Querystring is undefined. That means the import went wrong somewhere. Are you sure it is installed properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `jspm install querystring` will not install the library that you have mentioned. The command that you should run is this:

```
jspm install npm:qs
```

Then, you can import and use it like this:

```
import querystring from 'qs';
// call querystring.stringify(someObject);
```

Or

```
import {stringify} from 'qs';
// call stringify(someObject);
```